# Flexible column width based on image width inside (with fixed height)

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I've created a 10 column container using Elementor.

How can I set the width of the columns based on the width of images inside the column width fixed image heights? Like the example below:

[image: See attached]

My elementor setup is similar to this layout:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
        <img src="#">
        <h2>Book Title</h2>
        <h5>Author</h5>
        <p>Price</p>
        <button>Buy Now</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While you can get the required layout of 5 items per row using a set of grids (one per row) this layout won't work well for narrow viewports. What do you want to happen when the text is too wide to have 5 items per row?

Comment: How do you set fluid grids based on the image width though? I think for narrow viewports, i'll cut it down to 3 per row etc.

Comment: Yes, needs consideration. The layout you have shown in the picture only really works because it's book covers, ie mainly portrait with the odd square, nothing landscape - what would be needed for the Very Hungry Caterpillar?

Answer (score 0):

This is a sort of answer to the original question (2 rows of 5 entries in each) but obviously it isn't complete as there will need to be some additional way of dealing with narrow viewports or several wide-compared-to-high images.

I've put this snippet here in case it helps find a more general solution:

As you know you want 5 entries per line whatever the aspect ratios of their various images you could lay out each as a grid of 5 columns with the first image taking 50% (or whatever you require) of the overall height.

Each row is independent as you want it to adjust to its content's image aspect ratios with no regard for the column layouts of other rows.

View the snippet full page.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  width: 100vw;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.column img:first-of-type {
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300">
      <h2>Book Title</h2>
      <h5>Author</h5>
      <p>Price</p>
      <button>Buy Now</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300">
      <h2>Book Title</h2>
      <h5>Author</h5>
      <p>Price</p>
      <button>Buy Now</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/200">
      <h2>Book Title</h2>
      <h5>Author</h5>
      <p>Price</p>
      <button>Buy Now</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300">
      <h2>Book Title</h2>
      <h5>Author</h5>
      <p>Price</p>
      <button>Buy Now</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300">
      <h2>Book Title</h2>
      <h5>Author</h5>
      <p>Price</p>
      <button>Buy Now</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/400">
      <h2>Book Title</h2>
      <h5>Author</h5>
      <p>Price</p>
      <button>Buy Now</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300">
      <h2>Book Title</h2>
      <h5>Author</h5>
      <p>Price</p>
      <button>Buy Now</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300">
      <h2>Book Title</h2>
      <h5>Author</h5>
      <p>Price</p>
      <button>Buy Now</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/100/300">
      <h2>Book Title</h2>
      <h5>Author</h5>
      <p>Price</p>
      <button>Buy Now</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/200">
      <h2>Book Title</h2>
      <h5>Author</h5>
      <p>Price</p>
      <button>Buy Now</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey A Haworth, it's looking great and in the right direction!! However, I'll need the 10 items to be in the same container (split into 5 items per row), as it'll need to be a dynamic  list of items (book ranking) using an elementor plugin.